# If $x\sqrt {1-y^2} + y\sqrt {1-x^2}=a$, show that

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $x\sqrt {1-y^2} + y\sqrt {1-x^2}=a$, show that $\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2} =-\dfrac {a}{(1-x^2)^{\frac {3}{2}}}$

I thought of using implicit differentiation, but it needs to be used twice which is cumbersome and complex. Isn't there any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

WLOG $x=\sin A,y=\sin B$ where $\dfrac\pi2\le A,B\le\dfrac\pi2$

$$\implies\sin(A+B)=a$$

$$ \arcsin a=\arcsin x+\arcsin y$$

Comment: How do I find the second derivative after that?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=?$$

Comment: I didn't get that though.

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., Can't u differentiate   $$ \arcsin a=\arcsin x+\arcsin y$$?

Comment: how to differentiate $arc sin(y)$ and $arc sin (a)$?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., $$\arcsin(a)$$ is constant, right? and $$\dfrac{d(\arcsin y)}{dy}=\dfrac{d(\arcsin y)}{dy}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=?$$

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

solving your equation for $y$ we get
$$y=a\sqrt{1-x^2)}-\sqrt{x^2-a^2x^2}$$ or
$$y=\sqrt{x^2-a^2x^2}+a\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
then you can differentiate this with respect to $x$

Comment: Why write $\sqrt{-(x-1)(x+1)}$ in place of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$??

Comment: sorry for that, it will be corrected!